# Subquery is having more than one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables as below:

**tbl_test**

```
OFID bigint
Offer_Text text

OFID    Offer_Text   
-------    ----------    
1014    Test1   
1015    Test2
```

**tbl_trans**

```
OfferNo nvarchar        

OfferNo       
---------    
1015    
1015   
1015   
1014
```

Now, I want an o/p as below

```
OFID    Offer_Text  Counter    
-------    -------------  -------  
1014    Test1       1   
1015    Test2       3
```

That means count of each OFID with the Offer_Text also..

Is it possible..?

What will be the correct query for this?

My Existing query is this:

```
SELECT 
   offer_Text, OFID, COUNT(OFID) as Counter 
FROM 
    tbl_Test as a, tbl_trans as b 
WHERE 
    cast(a.OFID as nvarchar) = b.OfferNo 
GROUP BY 
    a.OFID
```

But giving me the following error:

> Column 'tbl_Offer.Offer_Text' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

Comment: Two side-notes: **why** is the `OFID` a `BIGINT` but the `OfferNo` in your other table a `NVARCHAR`?? It's the same thing - no?? Should be the same datatype, too! ALso: don't use `TEXT` anymore - it's deprecated. Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure:

```
SELECT 
   OFID, Offer_Text,
   Counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM dbo.tbl_trans t
              WHERE t.OfferNo = CAST(OFID AS NVARCHAR(30)))
FROM
   dbo.tbl_test
```

Gives you your desired output of:

```
OFID  OfferText  Counter
1014  Test1        1
1015  Test2        3
```

**Update:** to have only those rows that exist in the `tbl_trans` subtable (a new requirement - not present in the original question!), you need something like this:

```
SELECT 
   OFID, Offer_Text,
   Counter = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM dbo.tbl_trans t
              WHERE t.OfferNo = CAST(OFID AS NVARCHAR(30)))
FROM
   dbo.tbl_test 
WHERE 
   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_trans WHERE t.OfferNo = OFID)
```

Comment: Yes..you are almost there..but this gives me all records from the tbl_test with 0 Counter where it does not match.
But I want only those records which matches with the OfferNo in tbl_trans table..

Comment: @VishalSuthar: that's a **new requirement** which didn't have in your original question! I've updated my answer with one solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   OFID, Offer_Text,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_trans t2
    WHERE CAST(t1.OFID as nvarchar) = t2.OfferNo) AS Counter
FROM
   tbl_test t1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also reeturn results where there is a ofid in test that does not match agains any in the trans table:

```
select te.*, count(tr.offerno) as counter from tbl_test te
left join tbl_trans tr
on te.ofid = tr.offerno
group by te.ofid, te.offer_text
```

For example if you had a `1016` in the test table, this will return:

```
OFID    Offer_Text  Counter    
-------------------------- 
1014    Test1       1  
1015    Test2       3
1016    Test3       0
```

If `1016` shouldn't be there just remove the word `left` from the query :)

**NOTE:** Tested the join and it should work regardless of the difference in the data types

Comment: Well the join will only work if all the values in the table column convert without error. Otherwise the statement will error out.

Comment: Good point. I assumed from the sample data it would be that way